# Where has the audio gone on my iPhone?

Tags: iphone, audio

I have a problem with my iPhone 11 - the handset audio device has disappeared so I cannot make calls, play music etc from the speakers on the device.  I cannot change the volume.  When I long press on the volume control in control centre it appears as a full white bar, which I cannot adjust.  When I long press on the media controls in control centre there is no "iPhone" item in the device list, and the scrubber on the volume control is missing.
See images below.

Using headphones works fine, but currently there is no way to make the handset device make a sound!

[image: No audio devices]
[image: Full volume control]

Comment: Have you tried a [force reset](https://support.apple.com/guide/iphone/force-restart-iphone-iph8903c3ee6/ios) of your iPhone?

Comment: Thanks for the tip @IconDaemon.  I've tried that but the problem still persists